# Sstore key-values of sorted hashmap in string[]

Tags: java, hashmap

I am sorry for posting this unclear question. This is my first time using hashmap and hence i was confused. Have tried to explain this question in a better way here - [store key values of hashmap in string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415366/store-key-values-of-hashmap-in-string)

I have a sorted hashmap based on values. I want to extract the keys from the sorted map and store them in a String[] array. The order of the keys(sorted by values) is important.
I used this code to sort the hashmap on values - http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/306/

To extract the key array, I tried

```
 String[] keys = (String[])( hm.keySet().toArray( new String[hm.size()] ) )
```

(here hm is the hashmap)

But this method didnt work. The keys string[] has the keys but not in the sorted order I want.

---

Update:
I used linkedHashMap and was able to store the sorted key values in an array.  [Here](http://www.lampos.net/sort-hashmap) is the link for the code.

Comment: You say you've got a "sorted hashtable" - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: what didn't work? Was the order not as you expected it to be?

Comment: sorry its a typo.. I have sorted a hashmap based on values

Comment: "sorted hashtable based on values" how did you get this? sorted externally and then inserted into the map because then the order will be lost; use linked hashmap or any such variant for that. For "sorted hashtable" data structure, are you using concurrentskiplistmap? please elaborate "sorted hashtable"

Comment: Show us the code where you sort the HashMap. A HashMap can't be sorted, so a "sorted HashMap" confuses us.

Comment: editing the question with the code..

Answer (score 2):

Based on the typo, and your clarification that you are using hashmap, the order of the keys retrieval will not be consistent with the insert order. Use LinkedHashMap for that. This is using you do external sorting and then insert sorted entries into the map.

If you want the entries to be sorted while they are being inserted into the Map, use TreeMap. You can either use a custom comparator or make your key object implement Comparable interface.

Comment: Or TreeMap for "natural order".

Comment: or TreeMap with a Comparator for any order you like.

Comment: @EJP : yes, already mentioned in the answer (custom comparator for any ordering or Comparable for natural ordering). Maybe i needed to make it explicit that custom comparator is usually used for atypical ordering and comparable for natural ordering.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap uses key.hashValue() to sort the values. Use TreeMap instead.

Comment: No. It doesn't do anything of the sort.

Comment: is there anyway to extract the key values from a sorted hashmap and store them as string[]?

Comment: i know, but the order of the keys is not the same. I want the same order as it was after sorting.

Comment: @Umang So sort it. But that doesn't sort the HashMap, it sorts a copy of the Collection returned by keys().

Comment: ok.. I didnt know that! so is there any way to get the keys as an array sorted as they were in the collection?

Comment: @Umang This question doesn't make any sense. The keys() Collection is the keys() Collection, and it is in the order that it's in. It can't be in a different order from itself. I don't think you've understood much of what you've been told here and I also don't think you really understand your problem or requirement yet.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a sorted hashmap based on values.
>   I have sorted a hashmap based on values

No you haven't. A HashMap isn't sorted at all. You can get the values(), as a Collection, and you can sort that any way you like, but it doesn't sort the HashMap itself.

> But this method didnt work. It stores the keys in random fashion.

It isn't defined to do anything differently, especially as you haven't sorted the HashMap at all.

You need to clarify what you're talking about here. If you want to sort the values, do the above. If you want to sort the keys, do the above with `keys()` instead of `values()`'. If you want the Map itself sorted on keys, use a TreeMap. If you want the Map itself sorted on values, bad luck, you can't.

Comment: I know a hashmap isnt sorted on its own. I meant that i created a hashmap and then sorted it.

Comment: you can see the question for the link to how sorting was done

Comment: @Umang That link doesn't demonstrate sorting a HashMap at all. It shows code that returns a List that has been sorted. Nothing whatsoever has been done to the HashMap.

Comment: the link says on the top - "This following code outputs the elements of the map sorted by value." And its actually sorting based on values! I can see that!

Comment: @Umang and so it does, because it processed the sorted List. The HashMap itself *has not been sorted.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> hm = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("AAA", "typeAAA");
    hm.put("BBB", "typeBBB");
    hm.put("ABB", "TypeABB");
    String[] keys = hm.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    for (String key : keys) {
        System.out.println("key: " + key);
    }
}
```

The output would be:

```
key: AAA
key: ABB
key: BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you want the order of the keys of a `HashMap` to be the same as your sorted list of keys.  This is *simply not possible*.  A `HashMap`s keys are determined by the hash table algorithms; e.g. a complicated process that depends on the keys' hash values and sequence of insertions and deletions.

The closest you will get is to create a `LinkedHashMap`, and populate it by inserting entries from the old `HashMap` in the order of the sorted keys.  If you then iterate over the `LinkedHashMap`'s keys, you will get them back in the order in which they were inserted.  But this is a heavy-weight solution, and it breaks down if you subsequently have to add more entries to the "sorted" map.  It may be better to just use a `TreeMap`.

---

> I dont want to make changes to the hashmap. I just want to get an array with the keys in the order of sorted values.

In that case, you simply need to extract the HashMap's keys into an array and sort it.  The code has been given in other answers.

On the other hand, if you want to do something so that the map's keys always come out in the sorted order (which you seem to be saying in other comments), you **are** changing the map.

Comment: I dont want to make changes to the hashmap. I just want to get an array with the keys in the order of sorted values.