# store key values of hashmap in string[]

Tags: java, hashmap

Got the solution.. Used linkedHashMap and was able to store the sorted key values in an array. [Here](http://www.lampos.net/sort-hashmap)'s the link for the code.

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [store key values of sorted hashmap in string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414875/store-key-values-of-sorted-hashmap-in-string)

I created a hashmap and then 'sorted by value' the elements in the map using [this code](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/306/). 
The code worked and i was able to display on screen the key value pairs sorted by value.

Now I want to store the keys(from the sorted elements) in a `String[]`. `HashMap.keySet().toArray()` doesn't help as the entired HashMap are not sorted.

Can anyone please suggest a method to do this?

further clarifying the situation - Suppose I have key value pairs like (a,1)(b,23)(c,7)
by using the above link, i was able to get (a,1)(c,7)(b,23) as output. I want to store {a,c,b}  as a string array.
I hope the problem is clear now.

Comment: The above snippet does return an array of keys. I do not understand the problem. Do you want to sort the array?

Comment: If your question is unclear, don't ask a new one.  Instead edit the original question to make it clear.

Comment: This snippet returns an array of keys from the hashmap, but i want the array of keys from the sorted elements. I hope i am clear.

Comment: I have written an answer to the original question ... and I would **encourage** other people to do the same.

Comment: @Umang: May I ask you to close [your first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414875/store-key-values-of-sorted-hashmap-in-string) question regarding this topic to avoid any confusion?

Comment: I am not able to delete that question. That's why I added an apology on the top of the question and posted the link to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Reusing this code you would just use

```
List keys = sortByValue(m);
String[] keyArray = keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
```

Using generics would make this nicer.  I would also sort by Map.Entry (from entrySet()) which would be faster and simpler.

Comment: `new String[0]` is enough and it works well :)

Comment: True, But it creates another copy using reflections.  The `new String[0]` is discarded if it is not empty.  This works well if the collection is typically empty and you can make the `new String[0]` a constant. Otherwise its not as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Google Collection:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>( );
    map.put("ABC1", "VALUE1");
    map.put("ABC7", "VALUE1");
    map.put("ABC2", "VALUE2");
    map.put("ABC3", "VALUE1");

    Multimap multimap = TreeMultimap.create();

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet() ) {
         multimap.put( entry.getValue(), entry.getKey() );
    }


    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( multimap.values().toArray() ));
```

Comment: I dont want to sort the keys. I want to get the array of keys sorted by their corresponding values.

Comment: Are values unique or there can be dublicates?

Comment: there can be duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting my keys is simple, use [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

```
TreepMap sortedMap = new TreeMap(someHashMap);
String[] sortedKeys = sortedMap.keySet().toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is not really sorting the HashMap - it is merely returning the keys, sorted by their value:

So all you need is:

```
Object[] key_array = sortByValue(m).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go either for something like

```
private static String[] keysSortedByValue(final Map<String, String> m) {
    final String[] result = m.keySet().toArray(new String[m.size()]);
     Arrays.sort(result, new Comparator<String>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
             final String v1 = m.get(o1);
             final String v2 = m.get(o2);
             if (v1==v2) return 0;
             if (v1==null) return -1;
             if (v2==null) return +1;
             return v1.compareTo(v2);
         }
     });
     return result;
}
```

or use `Map.Entry[]` for greater efficiency (avoiding the lookup).